# Are counterfeit shares and the "short ladder attacks" purporting to use them, real?

Tags: stock-exchanges, shorting-securities, market-manipulation

## Are counterfeit shares and the "short ladder attacks" purporting to use them, real?

Hi, long-time SE user here. As I would like to attract users with actual industry experience or expertise, I'll be awarding +150 bounty to the best answer, and possibly +50 bounty for other informative answers.

#### Context

I'm aware of [Closing Shorted Positions via Short Ladder Attacks](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/135807/7997). There, the OP asked, *"Why wouldn't hedgefunds keep using a short ladder attack?"* to which someone answered that short ladder attacks are a fiction because NBBOs make them impossible. As someone with experience in the tech side of the industry though, I don't know if this argument is watertight—I explain why later. I don't feel extending discussion in comments there will work out, as the topic has numerous considerations, so I'm asking a question directly, with sources and quotes to focus argument.

The idea of "Short Ladder Attacks" appear to have originated from the 2014 source [Counterfeiting Stock](http://counterfeitingstock.com/CS2.0/CounterfeitingStock.html). I could not trace the author from the [homepage](http://counterfeitingstock.com/) or a WHOIS. Many have found this source through a [Seeking Alpha article](https://seekingalpha.com/instablog/11442671-gerald-klein/3096735-anatomy-of-a-short-attack) that referred to it, authored by Gerald Klein. (On this person I could only find several class actions they were a plaintiff in.<sup>[1](https://www.leagle.com/decision/infdco20180919d20) [2](https://casetext.com/case/zola-v-td-ameritrade)</sup>)

#### Are "counterfeit shares" real?

Whoever the author is, these are the claims they make. The numbering is influenced by paragraphs but also sometimes split by me; I'm trying to keep to one idea per number so people can refer to each clearly.

> 1. There are a variety of names that the securities industry has dreamed up that are euphemisms for counterfeit shares. Don't be fooled: Unless the short seller has actually borrowed a real share from the account of a long investor, the short sale is counterfeit. It doesn't matter what you call it and it may become non–counterfeit if a share is later borrowed, but until then, there are more shares in the system than the company has sold. [...] The creation of counterfeit shares falls into three general categories. Each category has a plethora of devices that are used to create counterfeit shares.
> 2. [a] Fails–to–Deliver — If a short seller cannot borrow a share and deliver that share to the person who purchased the (short) share within the three days allowed for settlement of the trade, it becomes a fail–to–deliver and hence a counterfeit share; however the share is transacted by the exchanges and the DTC as if it were real. Regulation SHO, implemented in January 2005 by the SEC, was supposed to end wholesale fails–to–deliver, but all it really did was cause the industry to exploit other loopholes, of which there are plenty (see [b] and [c] below). *[...]*
> 3. [b] Ex–clearing counterfeiting — The second tier of counterfeiting occurs at the broker dealer level. This is called ex–clearing. These are trades that occur dealer to dealer and don't clear through the DTC. Multiple tricks are utilized for the purpose of disguising naked shorts that are fails–to–deliver as disclosed shorts, which means that a share has been borrowed. They also make naked shorts “invisible” to the system so they don't become fails–to–deliver, which is the only thing the SEC tracks. The SEC does not examine ex–clearing transactions as they don't believe that Reg SHO applies to short shares held in ex–clearing. *[The author goes on to list 7 examples.]*
> 4. [c] *[This one's so long I won't even bother to include it.]*

It goes without saying that, admitting possibility of "counterfeit shares" does *not* mean short ladder attacks are real. (Trying to preempt misuse of this question for misinformation.)

#### Are "short ladder attacks" real?

And here are their claims regarding what they actually called a "short down ladder."

> 1. The Anatomy of a Short Attack — Abusive shorting are not random acts of a renegade hedge funds, but rather a coordinated business plan that is carried out by a collusive consortium of hedge funds and prime brokers, with help from their friends at the DTC and major clearinghouses. Potential target companies are identified, analyzed and prioritized. The attack is planned to its most minute detail. The plan consists of taking a large short position, then crushing the stock price, and, if possible, putting the company into bankruptcy. Bankrupting the company is a short homerun because they never have to buy real shares to cover and they don't pay taxes on the ill–gotten gain. *[...]* Typical tactics include the following:
> 2. [a] Flooding the offer side of the board — *[...]* The shorts manipulate the laws of supply and demand by flooding the offer side with counterfeit shares. They will do what has been called a short down ladder. It works as follows: Short A will sell a counterfeit share at $10. Short B will purchase that counterfeit share covering a previously open position. Short B will then offer a short (counterfeit) share at $9. Short A will hit that offer, or short B will come down and hit Short A's $9 bid. Short A buys the share for $9, covering his open $10 short and booking a $1 profit.
> 3. *[cont'd]* By repeating this process the shorts can put the stock price in a downward spiral. If there happens to be significant long buying, then the shorts draw from their reserve of “strategic fails–to–deliver” and flood the market with an avalanche of counterfeit shares that overwhelm the buy side demand. Attack days routinely see eighty percent or more of the shares offered for sale as counterfeit. Company news days are frequently attack days since the news will “mask” the extraordinary high volume. It doesn't matter whether it is good news or bad news. *[...]*
> 4. *[cont'd]* Global Links Corporation is an example of how wholesale counterfeiting of shares will decimate a company's stock price. Global Links is a company that provides computer services to the real estate industry. By early 2005, their stock price had dropped to a fraction of a cent. At that point, an investor, Robert Simpson, purchased 100%+ of Global Links' 1,158,064 issued and outstanding shares. He immediately took delivery of his shares and filed the appropriate forms with the SEC, disclosing he owned all of the company's stock. His total investment was $5205. The share price was $.00434. The day after he acquired all of the company's shares, the volume on the over–the–counter market was 37 million shares. The following day saw 22 million shares change hands — all without Simpson trading a single share. It is possible that the SEC has been conducting a secret investigation, but that would be difficult without the company's involvement. It is more likely the SEC has not done anything about this fraud. *[More details at the source but also [here](http://counterfeitingstock.com/CS2.0/CS5CrashingTheStock.html).]*

So, there you have it. There's *a lot* more at the source, but I think these excerpts give plenty of launching points for debunking or validating the idea of counterfeit shares and short ladder attacks.

#### Why I don't find the NBBO argument convincing enough...

Referring back to [Closing Shorted Positions via Short Ladder Attacks](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/135807/7997), here's why I felt the answers and comments fell short of my trust. No disrespect to anyone there.

> Any trader who bids less than NBBO to buy a security goes on the order book at a lower price as a limit order. The same holds true for a seller whose price is above NBBO. **The only way that traders can move price is more buying (or selling) volume that is available at current price.**

I just don't think that's *necessarily* true. (It might end up being true, but it's not a closed case for me.)

I know what an NBBO is—I've spent quite some time developing trading platforms—and in that time I've seen a staggering variety of exchange mechanics: dark pools, smart order routing techniques incorporating icebergs and stop triggers, funky exchange features like "mid-point dark crosses," groups of pegs that just sit outside like P+1, P+2, P+3, P+4, P+5. (And I thought I *had* seen that brokers can prefer executing against other specific brokers as long as they respect price priority.) Anyway, these examples aren't to argue that the NBBO can be violated (it can't), but I think the NBBO line of argument assumes that order books are comprised of static, vanilla limit orders that don't react to their environment. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think retail traders (or "traders") make up most of the order book. It's institutions, and the order book is full of dynamic orders that *do* respond to sell pressure.

Given the technology I've coded for institutions, I *can* imagine a coordinated attack that drives prices down. I think. (Consider this a hypothetical, just to show it's not that simple.) Algorithms and technical indicators *do* respond to sell walls and high-frequency sell-offs. (You think there aren't hedge funds on the other side of this game?) Orders are pegged to the inside or they're "feelers"—they disappear or shift around as the inside moves. So not only can a coordinated attack bring on pressure, but, **especially when there's significant profit to be made, why couldn't part of the strategy be to *intentionally* execute the inside at a controlled loss?** As long as part or most of those executions are against your friends who are in on the scheme (*i.e.* have planted bids on every price level, *especially* empty ones—fractional prices come to mind), you would be able to feign high volume while forcing prices down, triggering institutional reactions and retail panic, so that you can ease off the gas and let momentum do the work—then gas on, gas off—maybe a couple million dollars sacrificed each time—but to make a billion later.

Again, that's completely made up. I just want to highlight that markets are sophisticated, and I would rather see a sophisticated answer ruling out why scenarios such as mine aren't possible or effective. But more importantly, **why counterfeit shares and short ladder attacks *as described in the source, Counterfeiting Stock,* do or don't make sense.**

#### Disclaimer

I'm not trying to make short ladder attacks a thing. For full disclosure, I *am* surfacing from the echo chamber of WSB, but I also recognize all kinds of questionable analyses that have cropped up there—grasping at straws about SEC legalese, imaginative takes on basic things like T+2 Settlement, etc. I'm a long-time evangelist of the SE network and was surprised to see someone on WSB (r/wallstreetbets) link directly to this site, which is what motivated me to award bounties for a quality answer on the topic.

Comment: `As someone with experience in the tech side of the industry though, I don't think this argument is valid.` Why? You don't even need a national order book, all you need is some other buyer to start throwing wrenches in this whole "attack."  Which, by the way, assuming multiple disjointed order books without a NBBO, your attack would only hit one order book and could be readily arbitraged by a third party with access to a other orderbook. I think you are too quick in dismissing this fundamental impedament.

Comment: Maybe it was a little harsh, I've reworded. My skepticism doesn't come from doubting the constraints of NBBOs (or arbitrage that would occur in a fragmented market). It comes from doubting that the only way one can drive price downward is buy executing every order on the way down.

Comment: While I appreciate the effort made creating this question, there's a lot of conflated spaghetti thrown at the wall in the Seeking Alpha article and way too much to unpack here (too many statements of fact and too many questions) which may lead to closure.  In brief, a syndicate conspiring to drive share price down with shorting is collusion and is illegal.  That abusive tactic isn't a short ladder.

Comment: The description of a short ladder attack involving two parties (A and B) alternately playing tag by shorting shares and the other covering at that same price ignores the fact that when shares are bought by one to close a position, it offsets an equal sized long position taken by the other at that price. That doesn't drive price down. That's equilibrium. The essential component here is `The shorts manipulate the laws of supply and demand by flooding the offer side with counterfeit shares.` It's as simple as that.  Flood the market with naked (illegal) shorts and share price is forced down.

Comment: Right—the offsetting of an equal-sized long position—a trade, right?—or am I missing something? But in the hypothetical scenario, it would occur en masse against inside bids, strategically clearing out price level after price level at a partial loss against both colluding and non-colluding bids—but the latter adds extra volume, influencing algorithmic and institutional traders, and so on. Maybe you're saying that that is so obviously illegal collusion that they wouldn't get away with it.

Comment: (Sorry, I meant "the **former** adds extra volume," the trades with colluding partners.)

Comment: I don't know what inside bids are.  NBBO?  If yes then if a short selling syndicate attacks, they have to short additional shares (new legitimate short positions and/or new naked shorts)  to take out the size at current price and move price down.  That's additional risk.  But this idea of two firms flip flopping the same number of shares back and forth and moving the market is nonsensical.  My key point is that they have to keep banging the bid, taking on more and more short positions to move price.  I think that we're on the same page with this.

Comment: Yup, we're actually on the same page about that, cool. It's the flip flop we might understand differently. A, B, C are friends. 20K buys on the order book at inside price P. A and B each post buys of 40K @ P, making the total inside bid quantity 100K. C shorts all 100K @ P, clearing out that price level. The official volume traded @ P is 100K but 80K of it is "owed" to friends, a wash because this is their plan. Now say @ P-1 there are 30K buys. This time A and C each post 40K @ P-1. It's B's turn to short all 110K @ P-1, clearing it out. The official volume traded @ P-1 is 110K ... and so on.

Comment: Are they taking undesirable liquidity as they short execute down? Yes—to be exact in my example, 20K*P + 30K*(P-1) so far. But they're doing so inflated volume and a calculated approach. Also on their way down, anywhere liquidity doesn't exist (fractional cents) their flip flops are 100% wash, yet register as real volume of trading. So that's how I think the flip flop might benefit them: inflated price-volume momentum. It would be especially beneficial in periods of low aka "non-friend" volume, aka afterhours, premarket, and while brokers have (purportedly) halted buying.

Comment: Note what you're talking about is not what the SeekingAlpha author describes (and please do read the rest of his piece more carefully: traders pulling cash out of ATMs, shorts putting mole janitors in company, being hoaxed by the humorous Confessions of a Paid Stock Basher - he's some way short being of a reliable source, no pun intended).

You can absolutely spoof volume; I suspect it would fall foul of the spoofing rules but we're assuming abusive naked shorting anyway. It's not clear it helps...

Comment: ... Price volume momentum seems to be used more as a technical signifier of a trend reversal, which suggests it might have a little value to convince those using it for that to buy into a reverse on an uptrend on low volume but would not be useful to use to continue a downtrend.

Comment: Thinking about this further - this approach seems very risky if someone sticks a fat bid order in slightly higher up as you're doing this, no? You're opening yourself to extending the sale by your full inflated volume. Better would be to fill a lot of high frequency transactions in the middle of the spread if you were trying to inflate volume and bail as soon as you're not matching your own orders.

Comment: @Andrew Cheong - If C shorts 100k shares at some price and A and B buy them, it's an offset and that does not move price.  No matter how many traders play games swapping shares at that a given price, price goes nowhere. In order for C to drive price down, he has to take out all shares bid at the current price. If he keeps doing this, share price continues to drop until buying volume exceeds selling volume.  Note that C has to devote more and more capital to achieve this repeatedly. Where this falls apart is if shorters floodi the market with naked shorts, swallowing bid volume illegally.

Comment: @BobBaerker: Even if short sellers had an almost unlimited ability to flood the market with naked shorts, the only way I could see them profiting would be if this induced others to sell.  Otherwise, if anyone was buying the stocks that were being shorted at a discount, the people who shorted them would have to buy them back at a higher price.  I can believe that naked shorting may sometimes induce enough panic selling to outweigh discount buyers, but is there any *other* mechanism by which it would be profitable?

Comment: @supercat - If there is an unlimited supply of naked shorts, it takes out every buyer at the bid.  When that happens, the next highest bid (at a lower price) becomes the NBBO quote. Legitimate sellers see this and lower their ask price.  Share price drops.  Lower and lower share price induces more people to sell.  It all cascades, perhaps creating panic selling (profit taking and  traders cutting their losses), perhaps sped up if there is significant naked shorting.

Comment: @BobBaerker: Is there any mechanism, *other than the inducement of panic selling*, by which naked selling would yield a net profit after the shares are bought back?  If some of the shares are scooped up by value buyers at a price which is 75% less than even the lowest plausible estimate of a company's per-share net asset value, and those buyers would demand four times what they paid to sell them back onto the market (why should they sell them for less?), I don't see any way for the short sellers to unwind their positions without a major loss unless panic selling outweighs value buying.

Comment: @BobBaerker - You're last comment is what I'd been trying to say—but there were probably nuances of your side I wasn't getting.

Comment: @supercat - You're getting lost in the details: naked shorting, the company's per-share net asset value, panic selling or not, what buyers demand, value buying,  etc.   It's really quite simple.  The big picture is that those who sell high and buy low make money.  Those who buy low and sell high  make money.

Comment: @Andrew Cheong - The GME short is a complex process that can't be explained simple because multiple events have to occur to lay the groundwork and multiple events can contribute to its size and speed.  I've done plenty of delta neutral ehdging with options so I've understood how option market makers hedge options (in this case, calls bought by Redditors), I never connected those dots to a short squeeze (a gamma squeeze).  Live and learn :->)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One starting point is to note that, on "lit" electronic exchanges as in most or all dark pools, market participants do not get to know who exactly they are trading with.  Thus, the scheme is *already* technically impossible as described because A has no way of selling directly to B, nor B back to A, and so on.

That leaves our schemers with something weaker to try: they can all agree that they will do a bunch of selling (the same is true for buying of course).  They cannot know exactly *who* they will sell to, but they agree they will do a lot of it.   The net effect of all these sales will be no different from the effect of a *single* firm just trading a lot of shares, so it is not really necessary to assume some kind of collusion.

Now, making a lot of sales is not illegal *unless it is done with the [purpose of manipulation](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Ehcs14/SX9.htm)*.  That is as true for a single firm as for a cartel.  It is slightly more illegal for a cartel to do it, but either way it is not allowed.

As commenters have noted, there is no way for our seller(s) to *keep* the stock price down without committing ever-increasing amount of capital.  So artificially depressed prices like these will rebound unless either (A) panic is induced (@supercat comment) or (B) the new price is seen to be an epiphany revealing corrected firm value by the broader market.

That is to say, prices will rebound unless our cartel gets significant  *non-cartel* participants to agree that the "fair" price truly is closer to this low new price, which is not part of the "attack" premise.  Hence prices will rebound.   The rebound will put the seller in a huge negative PL situation.  Thus, it is not really a smart strategy.

The one place you *do* see firms actually trying these sales floods is when they can make the new price "stick" for a while;  namely, at the end of the trading day.  If a firm can push the price down a few bucks just as markets close then their overnight capital requirements may be reduced.  Firms get caught (and fined) for that a dozen times a year or so in the US markets.

I also want to comment that the word "ladder" in the phrasing "ladder attack" lends zero clarity to the idea, and just serves to make it sound more menacing through its obscurity.

**Conclusion:**  "ladder attacks" are impossible as described, are a great way to lose money if you analyze something close to what's described, and are illegal anyway, with attempts at this sort of thing being constantly monitored by regulators.

Edit:
Here is a [technical paper](https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/chriss/optliq_f.pdf) describing a famous model of price rebounds

My qualifications:
I hold a Series 57 qualification, worked on trade execution algorithms (theory and C++ code) for a decade at a former employer, and teach some of this stuff at a top-10 US university.

Edit 2:
I realize I should also address the following bit of silliness:

```
 The plan consists of taking a large short position, then crushing the 
 stock price, and, if possible, putting the company into bankruptcy
```

The traded firm has *already received* the money for its shares in the IPO, and in secondary offerings, etc.  It never gets any more.  Unless the firm has imminent prospects of issuing *more* shares, a crash in share price has *zero* effect on the finances of the firm and could not possibly affect the likelihood of bankruptcy.

Comment: "a crash in share price has zero effect on the finances of the firm and could not possibly affect the likelihood of bankruptcy."  I disagree. A companies stock movement downward will affect line of credits and cash flow.

Comment: @paulj  On the contrary, where lines of credit and other loans exist, their T&C/covenants are at best infrequently attached to stock price.  In no small part, this is in service of operational uniformity -- i.e. because bank loan desks deal with many client companies that are not publicly traded, and hence have no externally-available stock price at all.

Comment: Folks may be interested to read about another common type of illegal market manipulation, pretty much the opposite of what is being discussed here.  Namely, if someone wants to sell for a nice high price, they put in a bunch of *buy* orders at a price at or below the national best bid (NBB).  This way *other* market participants erroneously perceive a lot of buying interest, and adjust their quotes upwards.  It is called [spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoofing_(finance)), and every year various jail terms and fines arise from miscreants using it.

Comment: This is a great answer. Describes both the way it is technically possible [though not in coordination of buying and selling to directed parties, but rather through flooding the market and trading with any and all] but also generally financially prohibitive.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I was looking for someone who would take me up on the argument, _"Why couldn't taking out price levels strategically, at a controlled loss, be part of a strategy toward creating calculated price depressions / panic."_ I feel you've heard me here, and are still saying it's prohibitively expensive, and I also must be underestimating the resilience of price targets. My perception was that the markets were a frenetic, tentative equilibrium between tons of participants (and algos) with conditional targets, therefore susceptible to manipulation. But you seem to be saying that

Comment: actually price targets are quite solid and fundamentally derived—any number of participants would fill in temporary depressions immediately. Can I ask one question out of curiosity? About participants not being able to exchange with specific other participants. Is that not viable using fractional prices and / or dark pools or using other restrictions? (While developing trading platforms I remember certain kinds of orders could only execute against others of the same type, maybe something to do with special settlement terms, I don't know.)

Comment: @AndrewCheong On the "lit" US markets there are no real fractional prices, save perhaps mid-point matches for which I cannot remember whether half-tick is allowed.  When hidden like that they do not receive time priority.

Comment: (continued) Some dark pools separate their clients into sub-pools depending on what type of trading firm they are, but it is still not directable to particular counterparties.  Dark pool trades in the US of course still must attend to NBBO price priority.   Some foreign markets allow, say price-broker-time priority but that's a whole different set of securities.  It *is* possible for two counterparties to trade directly with each other over the telephone, but those trades would not make it onto the tape in the same way.

Comment: I just saw the CFTC numbers for 2020.  Not all of their actions are related to misbehavior of the variety discussed here, but there were over 100 "actions" taken with over $1B in fines, and over a dozen associated criminal prosecutions

Answer (score -7):

That counterfeiting stock article is the best. The answer is already there, you just need to read it again.

You are assuming short manipulators need to sell outside the NBBO to mount a short attack. They don't. All they need to do is keep selling at the NBBO. Due to the collusion, the shorts will always overwhelm the longs. And in many cases, it doesn't immediately lead to a crash. There can be a lot of long interest too when a stock becomes value, but the longs get frustrated because the stock price doesn't go up. Many times, the longs don't even realize the extent of longs and assume there is little long interest. It's confirmation bias from looking at the flaccid share price.

The truth is, a lot of longs bought counterfeit shares from manipulating shorts who never get to borrow as the shares count is limited. When these buy and sell orders match within a broker dealer, they cancel each other. As per the article, only shares that have no matching and hence don't cancel out within a broker dealer have to be reported to the DTCC where the broker dealer will be given 3 days to sort it out otherwise they become Failed to Deliver. To circumvent this, broker dealers collude among themselves to "match ex clearing". Given the right balancing act, manipulating shorts can keep selling without borrowing ad infinitum without triggering Reg SHO. Whether it triggers Reg SHO or not is immaterial. Triggering Reg SHO means manipulating shorts were caught. Most manipulating shorts aren't caught. In that article, the author mentioned a perfect case study, where one person had bought off the entire shares outstanding, but after that still seeing multi-millions amounts of shares "changing hands" after he supposedly bought the entire company! This is the biggest fraud in the history of finance, and must be stopped immediately.

Comment: I wasn't the first downvote but I also have to downvote; please know this is not a personal attack (I see you're new here). I was seeking an answer that adds credence to the pieces I quoted, using additional or more accessible and verifiable facts. You are mostly resurfacing pieces of the article in question. And: _"You are assuming short manipulators need to sell outside the NBBO to mount a short attack."_ No, I don't. (But I agree that a great many people do.) If your answer gets further downvoted or removed, please know it's because it's not an answer, not because of "manipulating shorts."

Comment: I think your answer can be salvaged though, if you try again and reply to _me_ (rather than who you might think I am, or people you want to argue against). If you have knowledge, I'm looking for a teacher. But I'm not going to listen to someone pointing to a sacred text that already tells it all.